# SQL query to get value for each and every age field value

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I am SQL/SQLALC beginner and require help

I have a SQL query

```
select count(*), age 
from report_definition 
group by age;
```

Now, this returns

```
count | age 
-------+-----
     2 |   6
     3 |   0
     2 |   3
(3 rows)
```

My expected output is to also get values for each and every age
for example

```
count | age 
-------+-----
     2 |   6
     3 |   0
     2 |   3
     0 |   1
     0 |   2
     0 |   4
     0 |   5
```

essentially, I want a query to return a 0 value if there are no records in that count.
can you also help me in telling the corresponding sqlAlchemy statement to SQL query

Comment: a little mistake for you example duplicate 3.

Comment: (SQL): Have a cte/help table that returns every integer value. Outer join.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul thanks, I have removed duplicate 3

Comment: @jarlh, can you explain how it is done, since I am pretty new to SQL and sqlAlchemy. thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about slqAlchemy but as a normal SQL problem, this is one approach (of many) that would give you the desired result.

First, create a lookup table of Age e.g. luAge with a unique list of your ages.

- luAge

| Age |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Then your query will give you values of zero in an example like this:

```
SELECT          a.age Age,
                COUNT(b.Age) [Count]    
FROM [luAge]    a
LEFT JOIN       report_definition b on b.age = a.Age
GROUP BY 
                a.Age
```

[image: Result Illustrated]

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the numbers from 0 to 6.  If you don't have a handy list available, there are various ways to create one.  One method just uses the table you have:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by age) - 1 as age
      from report_definition
     )
select count(*), n.age 
from n left join
     report_definition rd
     on n.age = rd.age
where n.age <= 6
group by n.age;
```

You might have a better way to generate the numbers; this works because your table `report_definition` has at least 7 rows.

Comment: thank you. will try this and  see if this works